# Simple hello world using jQuery ajax and php doesn't works

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do a simple `hello world` using jQuery and Ajax for getting a response from a php in the same folder.

The jQuery code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://pingendo.github.io/pingendo-bootstrap/themes/default/bootstrap.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function jsonIt(){
            var x = document.getElementById("input1").value; 
            var y = document.getElementById("input2").value; 

            var obj = '{'
                       +'"id" : "'+x+'",'
                       +'"name" : '+y+''
                       +'}';

            var person = {
                id:x,
                name:y
            }; 

            var str_json = JSON.stringify(person);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: 'a.php',
                dataType: 'text', 
                data: obj,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function(e){
                        console.log(e.message);
                        //alert('error');
                    }
            });
            alert("Pause");
        }


    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <label for="inputEmail3" class="control-label">Email</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <label for="inputPassword3" class="control-label">Password</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="jsonIt()">Sign in</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Simply, called using the HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="jsonIt()">Sign in</button>
```

And the php, in the same folder, called a.php is:

```
<?php echo "Helo world"; ?>
```

So when I click the button that calls the function `jsonIt()` I get the following response: "[object XMLDocument]" and not Hello world.

What could be?

**EDITED**

After the modifications the header code will be:

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        ...

         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                function jsonIt(){


                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'get',
                        url: 'a.php',
                        done: function(data) {
                            alert(data);
                        },
                        fail:function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                            console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                        }
                    });

                    //alert("Pause");
                }

                $(document).on('click', 'button[type="submit"]', function(e) {
                     e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default click action
                     jsonIt();
                });
            });


        </script>
    </head>
```

And the markup of the button like:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Sign in</button>
```

But it stills returning me "[object XMLDocument]" and not Hello world.

Comment: How are you calling your AJAX function? Can we see that code/markup? Have you looked at the console for errors? Have you included the jQuery library? Do I ask too many questions? Would you like a [tutorial](http://www.jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)?

Comment: Is there more JS code, or is that it? your data object, `obj`, is never defined anywhere.

Comment: pass one more option to ajax call `dataType:'text'` or `processData: false` then it wont try to create json object from the response

Comment: @mituw16 the php file doesn't actually use the data from `obj`

Comment: @AlexAndrei I'm aware, but that JS variable is never defined, which could be causing the undefined JS error OP is seeing in the browser console.

Comment: Be more specific, are you seeing the alert or the console.log from the ajax call, or in other words, does it succed? Where does the *"no elements found"* error message come from, generally PHP doesn't have such a message by default ?

Comment: Can we see your markup?

Comment: I edited and posted all the JS code, and yes, I'm addiding the Jquery library using: <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: Can you post the exact error message from your browser console?

Comment: Are you sure the page is not refreshed? You don't seem to cancel the submit event but I don't know if there is a form as well.

Comment: Ok, i have a little error with the jquery link, now i'm getting this return code: [object XMLDocument]

Comment: Without your markup we're not going to be able to offer any further help, we'd just be guessing.

Comment: i thought you said this was a simple "hello world" script. It is far from that. You need to surround your jQuery code with a document ready handler.

Comment: I'm in proces to do something more complicated but for the moment the script only should return "hello world"...  the a.php is simple and the ajax object too

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but, what is a "document ready handler"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to add jQuery scripts to the top of the page you need to surround them with a document ready handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    function jsonIt(){
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'a.php',
                //url: 'http://practica00.tk/a.php',
                dataType: 'text'
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                })

            .fail (function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                    console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                });
        alert("Pause");
    }

    $(document).on('click', 'button[type="submit"]', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default click action
        jsonIt();
    });
});
</script>
```

The document ready handler insures that all of the DOM has loaded before the jQuery runs and attaches its event handlers. If you don't wrap in a document ready handler the jQuery may attempt to attach event handlers and methods to items which are *not yet loaded into the DOM*.

You really shouldn't use inline JavaScript to call functions, especially since you have jQuery available to you. If you are going to you still need to prevent default actions.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="jsonIt(); return false;">Sign in</button>
```

If you'd like to use jQuery for the click you would remove the inline JavaScript from the button and add the following to your jQuery code:

```
 $(document).on('click', 'button[type="submit"]', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default click action
     jsonIt();
});
```

I'm not sure why you're doing anything with a JSON string as you do not use it in your query anywhere. you never define the `obj`, so you shouldn't send it.

**EDIT:** I have updated my answer to reflect the more proper AJAX return methods with the version of jQuery being used.

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

If you want to do a simple "hello world" you should remove any code that distracts from the purpose before adding any complexity.

**Additionally:** To perform AJAX (and consequently PHP) you must execute the code from an operating web server, either your localhost or a test host where everything can be executed properly.

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Comment: the obj is  defined but i will use it in the futur php code. In other hand, the error stills with the returned code that is: [object XMLDocument]

Comment: Did you change `type: 'get'` to `method: 'get'`?

Comment: Yes I change it and now i haven't any response... In the console it says in a.php no elemtns found

Comment: No elements found is a JavaScript error, not a PHP error. Add `dataType: 'text', ` right after the `url` parameter. Looks like jQuery is trying to guess the return type. I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I tried but nothing... Maybe is the structure in the ready handler ? I put the exactly code inside the ready handler

Comment: Copy the jQuery code I have in my answer and place it in your page to test.

Comment: It don't works anything, also the alert("Pause"); don't work... Maybe there are an error in the "fail" parameter?

Comment: There must be other errors then, clicking the button is not calling the function.

Comment: the markup of the button is writted  in the question: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Sign in</button>

Comment: ^ no, the original has an `onclick()` function in it.

Comment: But at last is necessary?! I thought that i didn't need it! How I should write it? like the original?

Comment: I have edited again. Remove the inline JavaScript from your button. Then copy the jQuery, including the click function, to your page *exactly* as I have written it. Then let me know what happened.

Comment: I think there are an error in the "fail" parameter on ajax object

Comment: Once I solved the fail sintax error, the alert works but... any php response... only in the console "no elemnt found"

Comment: I mixed methods, my apologies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81900/discussion-between-jay-blanchard-and-selan).

Comment: Now i'm working via the folder htdocs of Xampp under Linux. When I call  the Ajax object like you write it, it shows like that http://pasteboard.co/1BGEQBjw.jpg . This is the code, the console and how the webpage lookslike. At last, remembor I'm working with Lampp under his directory with all the components.

Comment: From that it looks like everything is working @selan

Comment: But the alert with the "hello world" message that should show didn't appear!

Comment: Did you follow the tutorial link I provided? I only have a short time to help this morning.

Comment: Don't worry, I will restart the project, I don't have a lot of time too and maybe is better to restart all the steps and keep calm!

Comment: I should be back later in the day if you need help.

Comment: I found it! It was a sintactic error in the .done and .fail declaration: it must be outside of the ajax object declaration, like in your tutorial! Thanks for your help!! I have taken the liberty of change it on your response!